# Get Laplacian pyramid using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to get a layer of the **Laplacian pyramid** using the opencv functions: `pyrUp` and `pyrDown`.

In the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=pyrup#cv2.pyrUp) and in more detail in this [book](http://books.google.be/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=laplacian%20pyramid%20opencv&source=bl&ots=hSJ97feFKg&sig=g7UTzcN8ALGzAFLtfNhmoM-n5Ig&hl=en&sa=X&ei=M2OcUf2qJKHi4QTJ4YHwAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=laplacian%20pyramid%20opencv&f=false), I found that the *i-th* Laplacian layer should be obtained by the following expression:

Li = Gi - pyrDown(Gi+1)

where Gi is the i-th layer of the Gaussian pyramid.

What I've tried is:

```
def get_laplacian_pyramid_layer(img, n):
    gi = img
    for i in range(n):
        gi_prev = gi
        gi = cv2.pyrDown(gi_prev)
    pyrup = cv2.pyrUp(gi)
    return cv2.addWeighted(gi_prev, 1.5, pyrup, -0.5, 0)
```

But I get different sizes of the images involved in the substraction. I don't understand it because `pyrUp` is suppposed to invert the process of the Gaussian pyramid, i.e. pyrDown (with a lose of information of course but that should not affect the size, right?).

**UPDATE**

I refactored my code to:

```
def get_laplacian_pyramid_layer(img, n):
'''Returns the n-th layer of the laplacian pyramid'''  
    currImg, i = img, 0
    while i < n: # and currImg.size > max_level (83)
        down, up = new_empty_img(img.shape), new_empty_img(img.shape)
        down = cv2.pyrDown(img)
        up = cv2.pyrUp(down, dstsize=currImg.shape)
        lap = currImg - up
        currImg = down
        i += 1
    return lap
```

As you can see, I force the destination image to be of the same size of the source with the parameter `dstsize` of the `pyrUp` function.

However, this code also gives me an error when when executing the `pyrUp` function. The message of the error is:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (std::abs(dsize.width - ssize.width*2) == dsize.width % 2 && std::abs(dsize.height - ssize.height*2) == dsize.height % 2) in pyrUp_,

In debug mode I checked the expression of the assertion with:

```
up.shape[1]-down.shape[1]*2 == up.shape[1] %2 and up.shape[0]-down.shape[0]*2 == up.shape[0] %2
```

and it is satisfied.

So, I don't have a clue of what is happening.

Comment: You can pyrdown [2N+1] -> N, but pyrup N -> 2N. So make sure dims are even at all steps.

Comment: You could used `for i in range(n)` instead of `i = 0`, `while i < n` and `i += 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you use pyrDown on your input image *img* in every iteration

```
down = cv2.pyrDown(img)
```

I suggest you change that line to

```
down = cv2.pyrDown(currImg)
```

so you actually compute the next pyramid layer.

The reason for the error is your down image. Its shape is width/2 x height/2 compared to the input image

```
down = cv2.pyrDown(img)
```

yet you try to store its pyrUp result (width * height) in a much smaller up image with its shape beeing smaller (width/2 x height/2) due to

```
up = cv2.pyrUp(down, dstsize=currImg.shape)
...
currImg = down
```

Even if my answer is too late, maybe it will help someone else

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what I think is happening:

After the last iteration lets say gi_prev size is 11x11, so gi size is 5x5 (because it can't be 5.5x5.5). Then pyrup will be 10x10, not 11x11.

I would print out the sizes and check whether this is the case.

Comment: I updated my question after trying to solve the problem using your comment but I could not make it work yet.

Answer (score 0):

> However, this code also gives me an error when when executing the pyrUp >function. The message of the error is:
>
> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (std::abs(dsize.width - ssize.width*2) == >dsize.width % 2 && std::abs(dsize.height - ssize.height*2) == dsize.height % >2) in pyrUp_,

Many years late to the party here, but here we go. When passing the upscaled image size using 'dstsize:

```
up = cv2.pyrUp(down, dstsize=currImg.shape)
```

the .shape method returns height x width. However, the pyrup function requires these dimensions as width x height. Therefore try the following code:

```
up = cv2.pyrUp(down, dstsize=(currImg.shape[1],currImg.shape[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("c:/samples/lena.jpg")
layer = img.copy()

gp = [layer]

for i in range(6):
    layer = cv2.pyrDown(layer)
    gp.append(layer)
    cv2.imshow(str(i),layer)

layer = gp[5]
cv2.imshow('upper',layer)
lp = [layer]

for i in range(5,0,-1):
    guassian_extended = cv2.pyrUp(gp[i])
    laplacian = cv2.subtract(gp[i-1],guassian_extended)
    cv2.imshow(str(i),laplacian)   
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```